# Why aliasing not work in this query in Oracle Database?

Tags: sql, oracle19c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6Ip9.png)
In the above query why aliasing does not work properly and it gives error?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2E14N.png)
When i remove the **as** keyword it works fine but why?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow
Please add codes as text (Not images) in the questions/answers please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Because that's what [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__I2126863) says. There is no (optional or required) `AS` keyword before `t_alias`.

Comment: The `AS` keyword is optional in the ANSI/ISO SQL specification; however, in Oracle, it is forbidden before table aliases (and @AlexPoole links to the documentation). Why do you think aliasing does not work properly?

Comment: @ADITYA - the error doesn't mean aliasing doesn't work, it means the syntax you're using do define the alias is wrong. Oracle doesn't allow the `AS` keyword for table aliases, as has already been explained. That is why your query works when you remove that keyword.

Answer (score 1):

The `AS` is only recommended for columns. To give an alias to a table you never use `AS`.